# Laravel image upload returns only partial object on some image

Tags: laravel, file, upload

I have build a file upload system with Laravel 5.6. I'm having the problem that some images can be uploaded while some result in a error. I found out that some images (the oimage bject) is missing a "filename" and "temp storage" value.

Object is completely filled except for those two values.

When I open the image, which will not upload, in a photo editing software tool and I re-save it on my desktop, the image will upload.

Personally I think it has something to do with colors (RGB format) or something.

Anyways, when I print my object with a working photo I get this:

`Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
(
    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => photo-1754.jpg
    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
    [hashName:protected] => 
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpMyw0zP
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpMyw0zP
)`

When I upload a photo that does not work I get this:

`Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
(
    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => natuurlijk_adverteren-1754.jpg
    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream
    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1
    [hashName:protected] => 
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
)`

Does anyone have a clue on what may be causing this problem and -or how to fix it? it only happens occasionally with specific photo's but then again... we can't have a upload form breaking because an image upload :P

Best regards

Comment: Have you allowed large enough files in your PHP configuration in `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` ?

Comment: Good suggestion thanks! I added my comments on the reply below @ Mayank.
Both settings are currently set to 128M so that should be good. We are using PHP7.2-FPM on Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this:

```
[error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
```

and

```
[error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1
```

the first file have no issue that's why the error is 0, but the second file is having some issues like invalid file or the file size is more than the allowed one in php.ini, that's why it is not showing other details.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!~that indicated that there is an error somewhere indeed. I tried checking my logs on the server but cannot find anything concerning this. I will double check my php.ini settings just to make sure they are set high enough.

Comment: post_max_size is set to 128M (for testing purposes) and upload_max_filesize is set to 128M as well. I tried various settings just in case. Tried 12M, 32M, 64M and 128M or both. The file that does not work is 2,3Mb in size, the one that does work (opened and saved in Gimp) is 2.0Mb in size. We are using PHP7.2-FPM on Apache. Both settings (128M) are also visible when doing a phpinfo().